# What is the difference between NSSortDescriptor and SortedArrayUsingSelector

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort array of strings by length. NSSortDescriptor worked but not SortedArrayUsingSelector.

Why is it?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"length" ascending:NO];

[inputArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

and

```
[inputArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(length)];
```

Comment: Well, one is an object class and the other is a function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call of `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method returns a sorted array, leaving the original array unchanged. On the other hand, `sortUsingDescriptors:` sorts a mutable array in place.

Another problem is that `length` returns a primitive, while the selector used for sorting is expected to return a comparison result:

```
@interface NSString(MyAdditions)
-(NSComparisonResult)compareLength:(NSString*)other;
@end

@implementation NSString(MyAdditions)
-(NSComparisonResult)compareLength:(NSString*)other {
    NSInteger a = self.length;
    NSInteger b = other.length;
    if (a==b) return NSOrderedSame;
    return a<b ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
}
@end
...
NSArray *sorted = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareLength:)];
```

you would get the results that you expect. You can also sort in place using `sortArrayUsingSelector:`

```
[inputArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareLength:)];
```

Comment: It did not work  NSMutableArray *inputArray = [@[@"hello", @"test", @"come", @"comehellotest"] mutableCopy];
    
    NSArray *s = [inputArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(length)]; output is <__NSArrayI 0x8c49f20>(
comehellotest,
come,
test,
hello
)

Comment: @Sandeep You are right, that wasn't it. I tried the solution from [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/157197-sorting-array-of-strings-by-string-length.html), but it did not work either. I figured out what's happening - please see the update.